# Sharing state variable across processes

Tags: android, service, ipc, sharedpreferences, process

I want to provide certain info (let's say a state variable - a boolean) across processes. The state of this variable is maintained by a service, other apps shall only be able to read it (not to modify it).

My first thought was the SharedPreferences but there's a note on the docs stating that SharedPreferences usage is not supported across multiple processes. That leaves me with service messaging, AIDL, intents and ContentProvider.

Service messaging or AIDL is out of the question because it always has an asynchronous part to it (as well as Intents). I also thought of ContentProvider but it seems a little bit exaggerated/bloated just for this. Writing to external storage would allow modification of the data by other processes.

So, am I missing anything or what I'm trying to accomplish really isn't possible? (or recommended for that matter)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> Service messaging or AIDL is out of the question because it always has an asynchronous part to it (as well as Intents).

Binding to an AIDL-based service is asynchronous, but that is done once up front. Calling an AIDL-defined method is synchronous.

> I also thought of ContentProvider but it seems a little bit exaggerated/bloated just for this.

Most of your choices will be similarly "exaggerated/bloated just for this".

> am I missing anything

You could use broadcast `Intents` to push changes to the value, particularly if the value does not change frequently. The challenge here is bootstrapping the initial value (e.g., App B is installed and needs the value from App A, but has to wait until the value changes and App A sends the broadcast). However, this might be worth considering if you will be reading the value a lot, as doing an IPC per read may add more overhead than it is worth.

Also, you may wish to reconsider whether having this dependency is a good idea in the first place. Using the nomenclature from my preceding paragraph, App B perhaps cannot exist without App A, if it needs some value maintained by App A. Since the user can uninstall App A at any point, this could cause problems. Also, if this flag is meant as some sort of control mechanism (e.g., please don't do X while the other app is doing Y), you will have problems, particularly on multi-core devices where both processes might truly be running simultaneously.

Comment: I'm using AIDL, but the binding being asynchronous is precisely my problem, since I need to read a value from the service right after I bind to it.

About Apps A and B; the case in which App B depends on App A is precisely my case. App A manages data that the service uses. App B logs into the service. The state variable (or flag) would be something like a 'isSessionActive' boolean.

Comment: @takecare: "I need to read a value from the service right after I bind to it" -- then use a `ContentProvider`, or combine the apps into one single app. "App A manages data that the service uses. App B logs into the service" -- since it sounds like neither app is useful without the other, why are they separate apps?

Comment: I have to have separate apps since the idea is to provide a service (it kinda works like a client-server model, being the service the server and, in this case, app B the client). App B is an example application, but there could be many more.